# Windows Service SQL Server Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-services

```
<add name="NuspayTransactionSecurityEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Security.NTPSecurity.csdl|res://*/Security.NTPSecurity.ssdl|res://*/Security.NTPSecurity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.10.11;initial catalog=SP_PROCESSOR;persist security info=False;;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="NPTransaction" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Transaction.NPTransaction.csdl|res://*/Transaction.NPTransaction.ssdl|res://*/Transaction.NPTransaction.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.10.11;initial catalog=SP_PROCESSOR;persist security info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="CBCommon" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Common.CBCommon.csdl|res://*/Common.CBCommon.ssdl|res://*/Common.CBCommon.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.10.11;initial catalog=SP_PROCESSOR;persist security info=True;persist security info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
<add name="ApplicationServices" 
     connectionString="data source=192.168.10.11;initial catalog=SP_PROCESSOR;persist security info=True;persist security info=False;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

My problem is Windows authentication is not working if I use this application as a Windows service but it's working well in an IIS web application.

Comment: Under which account your windows service run? Does that service account has permission on SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the service account which has configured to run windows service **does not** permission to connect to `SQL`?

If this is the case, you need to **make** sure the user under which the service is running has permissions within `SQL`.

If you look in System, Administrative Tools, Services and find your service. You can adjust the credentials associated with it.

When you run is `IIS`, the `identity` under which it is run is that of the `app pool identity` who's has permission to connect to SQL.

Often when we install services they install against the `Network Service or Local System` security principles. These shouldn't be given access to SQL.

You could also create an `SQL user` and use a **connection** string which implements `SQL authentication` instead.